# Multi sites using the same code different theme color and logo

Tags: css, angularjs, node.js, gulp

I will be using the same angular application for many sites, the only difference is going to be the color of the CSS and the logo. Therefore I decided to use LESS to declare a variable as a color of the theme and use it across each site.

my `index.html` is the default route, and it loads all of the `CSS` and `JS` files. 
so my Style file that is going to be generated from LESS using Gulp is going to be loaded in index.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.min.css" />
```

So, I am wondering about where exactly I can decide which site I'm on? and how can I decide that? The structure is not clear to me. do I need to create another `index.html` for the other app? and inject it's styling there? but all of the other files are the same which makes no sense to me to duplicate everything.

My application is using angular frontend and nodejs backend, can you help me in two approaches: one is how to manipulate it from Angular side?
and how to manipulate it from nodejs backend side?

Thanks!

Comment: the sites are on different domain ? I so you could check which one is the current domain and use `ng-if`directive to set your css file for the right domain

Comment: You could ask for a config variable in the pre-rendering body and then respective files and config accordingly. We do that to distinguish between development, staging and production ENVs

Comment: @AkarshSatija sounds useful but not very clean can you describe some more?

Comment: @Merlin would work but looking for a better approach that can be extended... if your custom files per site grow, you will need to duplicate all ng-ifs for each site for all files. plus placing config in html does not sound great